# Getting selected layer name in QGIS Modeler

Tags: qgis, layers, qgis-modeler

If I have a geoalgorithm in my model and I want the value from one the parameters, then how can I get it? For example I want the layer name in the parameter `layer` in below figure so I get the value `Pts1`.

[image]

Comment: Is the layer name hard-coded into your model or is it one of the inputs of the model?

Answer (score 2):

Don't think you could do this directly through the modeler but you could create a **custom script** which, when run can simulate a model, allows you to fetch the name of the layer and use it for processing.

The following script uses the **Field Calculator** tool which creates a new field with the layer name and populates the values with the layer name (the python command is `layer.name()`):

```
##Fetch layer name=name
##Layer=vector
##Result=output vector

layer = processing.getObject(Layer)  
processing.runalg("qgis:fieldcalculator", Layer, layer.name(), 2, 99, 0, True, "'" + layer.name() + "'", Result)
```

[image: Script interface]

[image: Results of script]

You can have a look at the documentation on how to create scripts and call various functions and their associated parameters:

[Using processing algorithms from the console](http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html)